# Searching a HashSet for any element in a string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, search, hashset

I have a HashSet of strings and an array of strings. I want to find out if any of the elements in the array exists in the HashSet. I have the following code that work, but I feel that it could be done faster.

```
public static boolean check(HashSet<String> group, String elements[]){
    for(int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        if(group.contains(elements[i]))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's **O(n)** in this case (array is used), it cannot be faster.

If you just want to make the code cleaner:

```
 return !Collections.disjoint(group, Arrays.asList(elements));
```

Comment: I mean in this case, elements is array which cannot be O(1).

Comment: @Andrew White: Giving the benefit of the doubt for non-native speakers: perhaps what was meant was, " *the search* must be O(n); it can't be done in faster time than that." (**EDIT:** 卢声远 Shengyuan Lu's comment seems to affirm this.) I don't think the -1 is necessary.

Comment: O(1) is faster, but searching an array cannot be faster than O(n) without any other valid assumptions that can be made.

Comment: The array has unique elements, so could converting it to a HashSet somehow help?

Comment: Thats an elegant way to write it in one line, but I don't think thats faster.  `Arrays.asList()` is going to have some overhead in creating the list.  However, these days that kind of thing won't noticeably hit you in performance.

Comment: @user475021, converting an array to HashSet would still be O(n) at best, as it would have to loop over the array, adding each element. I think your solution is perfectly fine. It is both fast and readable.

Answer (score 2):

That seems somewhat reasonable.  `HashSet` has an O(1) (usually) `contains()` since it simply has to hash the string you give it to find an index, and there is either something there or there isn't.

If you need to check each element in your array, there simply isn't any faster way to do it (sequentially, of course).

Comment: if you want to make it barely faster, use ++i instead of i++.  I'm not sure if the compiler will optimize that for you.

Comment: I doubt that it will make any difference at all.  Besides, this kind of micro-optimization could easily turn into an anti-optimization when you move to a different Java implementation.

Comment: The compiler will optimize that for you. There are a bunch of answers on SO that explain why there is no difference between ++i and i++ :)

Comment: Well, that solves that then haha.  Thats interesting information, I'll have to look up some of those posts.

Answer (score 1):

> ... but I feel that it could be done faster.

I don't think there is a faster way.  Your code is `O(N)` on average, where `N` is the number of strings in the array.  I don't think that you can improve on that.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the slowest part of the algorithm is iterating over every element of the array.  The only way you could make it faster would be if you knew some information about the contents of the array beforehand which allowed you to skip over certain elements, like if the array was sorted and had duplicates in known positions or something.  If the input is essentially random, then there's not a lot you can do.

Comment: Actually, they didn't say that, and it is not true.  The slowest part will be the `contains(str)` call.  It has to call `str.hashCode()`, and then potentially compare `str` against one or more other strings in the same hash chain.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  What I meant was that O(n) for iterating over the array cannot be improved upon without prior knowledge of the contents of the array.  Thanks for helping to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the set is a sorted set, and that the array is sorted, you can get the [interval set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html#subSet%28E,+E%29) from the start to the end to possibly do better than O(|array| * access-time(set)), and which especially allows for some better than O(|array|) negative results, but if you're hashing you can't.